# Microsoft Speech SDK for iOS bitcode enabled

Tags: ios, azure, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services, bing-speech

Using the [SpeechSDK for iOS](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-STT-iOS). The application is not building because the SDK does not have bitcode enabled.

Cannot disable bitcode because the project uses Apple Watch component which mandates bitcode usage, disabling bitcode would mean disabling Apple Watch too.

**Any idea on how we can resolve this?**

Also, the framework is having two separate files for iPhoneOS and iPhoneSimulator, **is there a way to link those separate frameworks for both Debug and Release configurations in the app**.

Comment: did you try to reset bite code in your app setting?

Comment: @Gagan_iOS how would that help? we cannot disable bitcode because the project uses Apple Watch component which mandates bitcode usage, disabling bitcode would mean disabling Apple Watch too. anyways, whenever we add this SDK, we get a compilation error, don't know if bitcode is causing this